# Como chamar serviço REST na aplicação cliente com autenticação?

Tags: crux-framework

Olá!
Seguindo a documentação do Crux Framework é possível ver uma imensa facilidade em chamar um serviço REST de terceiros pela aplicação cliente utilizando o Crux. Mas quando a aplicação servidora possui segurança OAuth, existe uma forma de implementar esta autenticação na aplicação cliente utilizando o Crux? Estou me familiarizando com esta questão de segurança mas acho muito importante. Procuro uma documentação ou algum exemplo que implemente desta forma. 
Ou a forma correta seria implementar na minha aplicação servidora e consumir de lá? Obrigado!